# Delete twice on a derived object whose base class is a abstract class and overwrite operator new and delete function cause SIGTRAP on CLion

Tags: c++

I use the following code to simplify my real-world problems. I have a base abstract class and it overwrite operator new and operator delete function. The operator delete function doesn't free the memory (which I intend to do that). In my main function, I new a DeDerived object and delete this object twice. The program will interrupted by signal SIGTRAP on the second delete pb and stop at virtual ~Base(). And I want to know why?
Thank you very much!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() { cout << "destroy base class" << endl; }

    virtual void get() = 0;

    void *operator new(std::size_t size) {
        std::cout << "operator new" << std::endl;
        return std::malloc(size);
    }

    void operator delete(void *ptr) {
        std::cout << "operator delete" << std::endl;
    }

    int i;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    ~Derived() override { cout << "destroy derived class" << endl; }

    void get() override {
        cout << "Derived get" << endl;
    }

    int j;
};

class DeDerived : public Derived {
public:
    ~DeDerived() override { cout << "destroy dederived class" << endl; }

    void get() override {
        cout << "DeDerived get" << endl;
    }

    int k;
};

int main() {
    Base *pb = new DeDerived();
    pb->get();
    delete pb;
    delete pb;
}
```

Comment: _"I new a DeDerived object and delete this object twice. "_ - Why do you `delete` it twice? There should only be _one_ `delete` for every `new`.

Comment: I wish my real-world problems could be so-simplified. truly, I do.

Comment: Deleting any object more than once gives undefined behaviour.   This is true even if the object does not have an abstract class, and true even if any `operator new()` or `operator delete()` are overridden.

Comment: Mysql has several classes that automatically manage memory, I didn't know that before, so it cause me delete it twice.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `delete` on a pointer deallocates the associated storage and makes the pointer value invalid. It doesn't matter what `operator delete` does. Calling `delete` on an invalid pointer causes undefined behavior.

```
delete pb;
delete pb;
```

This has *always* undefined behavior. It doesn't matter what your `operator delete` replacement does.

---

Additionally, `delete pb` calls the destructor of the object, which ends its lifetime. Calling the destructor on the object whose lifetime has ended a second time also causes undefined behavior. So even just

```
pb->~Base();
pb->~Base();
```

has undefined behavior, although `operator delete` is not involved.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was comfused when the Base class is not a abstract class (i.e. th "get()" function is not pure virtual) and the program exit code 0. So it makes me think it is because the Base class is a abstract class, and the compiler do something special for abstract class when we delete it. Now, according to your answer, these behavior are are determined by the compiler, but the C++ standard defines these behaviors as undefined, right?

Comment: @Adia It doesn't matter what the properties of the class are. The standard says it is undefined behavior in any case. Having a virtual destructor is likely to result in more severe impact of this UB than e.g. a trivial destructor would.